# How to actualize the date of jspinner?

Tags: java, swing, date, jspinner

I have a Jspinner that have a date, the date can be choosed. However the date in jspinner should show the actual time when some time past, e.g. after 1 minute.

I tried something with a while loop or if.

How to change it ?

```
package datetest;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSpinner;
import javax.swing.SpinnerDateModel;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

public class DateTest {
 JFrame f;
 JPanel p;
 JSpinner sp;
 SpinnerDateModel dateModel;
 Date dates;
 Date dates1;
 DateFormat df;

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  new DateTest().startApp();
 }
 private void startApp() {
  f = new JFrame();
  p = new JPanel();

  dates = new Date();
  dateModel = new SpinnerDateModel(dates,null,null,0);

  sp = new JSpinner(dateModel);
  sp.setEditor(new JSpinner.DateEditor(sp, "HH:mm dd-MM-yyyy"));
  sp.addChangeListener(new CalendarListener());

  p.add(sp);

  f = new JFrame();
  f.getContentPane().add(p, BorderLayout.CENTER);
  f.setSize(450,550);
  f.setResizable(false);
  f.setVisible(true);
  f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
 } 

 private class CalendarListener implements ChangeListener {
  public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e)  {
  JSpinner jSpinner = (JSpinner) e.getSource();
  dates1 = (Date) jSpinner.getValue();
  df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm dd-MM-yyyy");
  String nt = df.format(dates1);
  System.out.println(dates1);
 }
}
}
```

Comment: So you are trying to "load" into the spinner the difference between two dates? Or are you trying to "load" a date?

Comment: How to refresh the time that is showed in the JSpinner or I have to add a JLabel with the actual time ?

Comment: You can call [JSpinner#setValue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JSpinner.html#setValue-java.lang.Object-) to refresh the spinner's value, wherever you need to.

Comment: Yes it works, but only when I push the button of the jSpinner.

Comment: where else do you want it to be working?

Comment: Thanks a lot. Maybe I misunderstood something. I thought the Jspinner Time must be refreshed approximately every second. But the important thing on the Program is that the User only have to input his Date in Future. And I must somehow implement a Filter to not allow a Date in the Past. Sorry, maybe another Question or Chat.